# How to use my own dependency resolver in MVC4's APIController

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

Back in MVC3, I had a custom `ControllerFactory` which would use my own container (as abstracted by my business logic) to instantiate controllers and pass them services they needed.

I'm trying to implement something similar in MVC4 using the new `ApiController`.

I've got a static/shared method `Core.DependencyResolverFactory.Resolver` which returns an `IDependencyResolver`. This in turn has a number of `Resolve(...)` and `ResolveAll(...)` methods and overloads.

So... How can I implement the same thing in MVC4?

I've tried setting up my own ServiceLocator but can't find the interface `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator` in any of the framework assemblies.

I'm not too worried about being tied to an underlying container as it's already being abstracted by the  BL, so really I just need a quick and dirty way to inject my classes into MVC's DI.

Can someone please point me at a good tutorial?

What I've got at the moment....

```
Sub Application_Start()
    ...Snip...

    'Suggested in the link on jrummel's answer...
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = New WebResolver
    'It fails due to DependencyResolver not being defined


    'I do have a 
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver = New WebResolver
    'but it's read-only and it is of type System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver not IDependencyResolver

End Sub

Private Class WebResolver
    Implements IDependencyResolver

    Private Resolver As Common.Interfaces.IDependencyResolver = Core.DependencyResolverFactory.QuickResolver

    Public Function GetService(serviceType As Type) As Object Implements IDependencyResolver.GetService
        Return Resolver.Resolve(serviceType)
    End Function

    Public Function GetServices(serviceType As Type) As IEnumerable(Of Object) Implements IDependencyResolver.GetServices
        Return Resolver.ResolveAll(serviceType)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API beta ships with its own `IDependencyResolver`, separate from MVC.

There's a tutorial on asp.net: [Using the Web API Dependency Resolver](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver)

You can get [ServiceLocator from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator).

Comment: Hmmm still hitting an issue... `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` is undefined. I have a `...Configuration.ServiceResolver` but it's read-only (and of type `DependencyResolver` not `IDependencyResolver`. I also can't see a `Set` method. I'll edit my Q for clarity

Comment: Ok, worth noting: This was changed from `ServiceResolver` to `DependencyResolver` between the Beta and the RC - I was still running the Beta. Thanks for your help

Comment: I thought that you always can implement Service Locator via some DI frameworks, but this is Antipattern. Am I wrong?